# How do I get URL rewrite to work in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, apache, mod-rewrite

I cannot manage to get any Laravel routing to work except the base URL and the files in the `/site/public/` folder.

`http://testurl/` (set through an apache vhost) works, and loads the home page.

`http://testurl/blog`) doesn't work (returns 404), but I would like it to.

Strangely, `http://testurl/index.php/blog` *does* work.

I have Googled in a hundred different places and looked at uncountably many StackOverflow questions and have tried everything that I could find, but nothing worked.

How can I fix this?

---

### Configuration info

I am running Laravel 5.7 on Apache 2.4.29 and PHP 7.1.9 on MacOSX 10.13.4.

I have enabled the rewrite module in `httpd.conf` like so:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
...
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` is set up like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/site/public"
    ServerName testurl
    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/site/public>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `.htaccess` in the `/site/public/` folder looks like this (I'd rather not have to change this):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My `config/app.php` has the following line:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://testurl'),
```

And last but not least, `web.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
Route::get('blog', function () {
    return view('blog');
});
```

If there is anything else that I am missing (or anything that I can try), please let me know.

Preferably, I would like solutions that won't require me to change my Laravel code when deploying to a server.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to crosscheck that you have `mod_rewrite` enabled

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya - It is indeed running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a LOT of searching I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/455190/cannot-get-mod-rewrite-to-work-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion) and it helped me find the answer.

All I needed to do was add `AllowOverride All` to my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/site/public"
    ServerName testurl
    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/site/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This corrected the issue, and now everything loads properly.